# How to delete the original files and keep only the versions using CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm trying this but without luck.

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  after :cache, :unlink_original

  def unlink_original(file)
    file.delete
  end

  .
  .
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

There was a typo in the docs.

Fixed it with the following.

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  after :store, :unlink_original

  def unlink_original(file)
    File.delete if version_name.blank?
  end
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: hi @KleberS thank for the solution it works fine, just have a question, there is a possibility that file which want to delete doesn't exist for some reason (bug or ...) ? this means : we don't need to add some verification like if File.exists? or something similiar ?

Comment: @medBo since it is a callback, we are assuming that the file was correctly saved. You can make a check like you mentioned, but it is an over check, IMO.