# Carrierwave - delete original before uploading to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm creating an app that takes a lossless audio format and compresses it before uploading the files to S3.  Because the original lossless files are very large, and I only need them for processing, I would like to delete the original files before uploading to S3.  However, I can't seem to get the file to delete.  I've found many similar guides, all which use [callbacks.](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-callbacks)    My current code looks like so in my uploader:

```
before :store, :unlink_original

def unlink_original(file)
  file.delete if version_name.blank?
end
```

I've tried this, along with a few other of the provided callbacks.  Either I will receive an error message (`undefined method 'delete' for nil:NilClass`), or the file will upload to S3, undeleted.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557911/how-to-delete-the-original-files-and-keep-only-the-versions-using-carrierwave

Comment: Hi @p4sh4, thanks for your response.  I tried out the link, as well as trying with a `before` and `after` filter, but my file is still being uploaded to S3.